# how to compare values of an array with a single value in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, compare, signals, speech

Can anyone tell me how to compare this for loop array value pp1 with the single value of pp. If the value of pp is present in pp1 then it must show 1 or must show 0. I'm getting 1 only  the last value of pp1. The code is:

```
[pp,pf1]=pitchauto(x,fs);

for ix=1:2
    V='.wav';
    ie=num2str(ix);
    Stc=strcat(ie,V);
    [x1,fs1]=wavread(Stc);
    figure,plot(x1);
    title('Test Audio');
    [pp1,pf1]=pitchauto(x1,fs1);
end

if (pp==pp1)
   msgbox('Matching');
else
   msgbox('Not Matching');
end
```

Kindly do reply with the correct answers.

Comment: The test comes after the loop, so of course you only get the last item. If you want to test each item in turn, put the test inside the loop.

Comment: Should i put that pp value inside the loop.

Comment: where i have to use **ismember**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You calculate a value for `pp1` each time, do nothing with it, then let the next loop iteration overwrite it. To make use of it, either put the test inside the loop:

```
for ix=1:2
    V='.wav';
    ie=num2str(ix);
    Stc=strcat(ie,V);
    [x1,fs1]=wavread(Stc);
    figure,plot(x1);
    title('Test Audio');
    [pp1,pf1]=pitchauto(x1,fs1);

    if (pp==pp1)
        msgbox('Matching', num2str(ix)); % show the index number as msgbox title
    else
        msgbox('Not Matching', num2str(ix));
    end
end
```

or collect the values of `pp1` in an array to test afterwards:

```
for ix=1:2
    V='.wav';
    ie=num2str(ix);
    Stc=strcat(ie,V);
    [x1,fs1]=wavread(Stc);
    figure,plot(x1);
    title('Test Audio');
    [pp1(ix),pf1]=pitchauto(x1,fs1); % assuming pitchauto returns a scalar
end

matchidx = (pp == pp1);
if any(matchidx)
    msgbox(strcat('Matching indices: ', num2str(find(matchidx))));
else
    msgbox('Not Matching');
end
```

If the values *aren't* scalar, then this approach is a bit more difficult - you could still use a matrix to collect equal-sized vectors, or a cell array to collect anything - but it's probably easier to stick with the first approach in that case.

Comment: The 1st code which you gave classifying each time the loop runs. The 2nd code works perfect. Thanks a lot once again